# juju local error ERROR could not connect before timeout

Tags: ssh, juju

`juju -v status`:

```
2013-04-07 18:11:20,888 DEBUG Initializing juju status runtime
2013-04-07 18:11:20,902:3553(0x7f739cef7700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@658: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.3.6
2013-04-07 18:11:20,903:3553(0x7f739cef7700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@662: Client environment:host.name=ubuntu
2013-04-07 18:11:20,903:3553(0x7f739cef7700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@669: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2013-04-07 18:11:20,903:3553(0x7f739cef7700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@670: Client environment:os.arch=3.5.0-26-generic
2013-04-07 18:11:20,903:3553(0x7f739cef7700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@671: Client environment:os.version=#42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 8 23:18:20 UTC 2013
2013-04-07 18:11:20,903:3553(0x7f739cef7700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@679: Client environment:user.name=alok
2013-04-07 18:11:20,903:3553(0x7f739cef7700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@687: Client environment:user.home=/home/alok
2013-04-07 18:11:20,903:3553(0x7f739cef7700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@699: Client environment:user.dir=/home/alok
2013-04-07 18:11:20,903:3553(0x7f739cef7700):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@727: Initiating client connection, host=10.0.3.1:50094 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=0x7f739c609700 sessionId=0 sessionPasswd=<null> context=0x3684740 flags=0
2013-04-07 18:11:20,903:3553(0x7f73984cb700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [10.0.3.1:50094] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2013-04-07 18:11:24,237:3553(0x7f73984cb700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [10.0.3.1:50094] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2013-04-07 18:11:27,573:3553(0x7f73984cb700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [10.0.3.1:50094] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2013-04-07 18:11:30,909:3553(0x7f73984cb700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [10.0.3.1:50094] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: txzookeeper.client.ConnectionTimeoutException: could not connect before timeout
2013-04-07 18:11:30,909 ERROR Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: txzookeeper.client.ConnectionTimeoutException: could not connect before timeout

2013-04-07 18:11:30,910 ERROR could not connect before timeout
```

Please anyone tell me what is the problem. I generated ssh keys:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and installed `juju` using guide on [juju.ubuntu.com](http://juju.ubuntu.com) 
but still getting this error, `cat .juju/environments.yaml`:

```
environments:
  sample:
    type: local
    control-bucket: juju-4fd5fb3fd7044bd9ac65a9c6bdc8aecd
    admin-secret: ffeb3c9a61e84155a04df9cf8db3e4fb
    default-series: precise
    data-dir: /home/alok/data
    ssl-hostname-verification: true
```

Comment: it doesn't look like it can find a zookeeper running on the localhost? did you bootstrap? if so please pastebin the output of bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I got similar behavior. I have nodes ready in MAAS and a "juju bootstrap" command succeeds. When I try to do any "juju -v deploy" or "juju -v status" an error is shown saying that a connection was refused. It kept retrying to connect to zookeeper on all kinds of different ports. It took probably about 5-7 minutes of waiting, but the status command finally succeeded. Now any subsequest status or deploy commands will work. Here is the output of "juju -v status" if it helps anyone. You'll notice the first time takes a long time, but the second one comes right up.

http://pastebin.com/jhvgDYK0